# How to make any matplotlib colormap a repeating cmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am ploting a map with matplotlib and I need to build a cmap that is like the 'prism' cmap. This cmap is repeating itself a high number of time.

I tried to build a cmap from a list of selected colors, but the colors do not display gradation.

The code I use is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "",
    np.concatenate([["#fb4747", "#315ace", "#b5f6e5", "#FFB347"] for i in range(40)]))
```

Now I am trying to build a repeating cmap using another matplotlib colormap. And I really need the shading in the colors. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You need to be aware of the fact that 4*40 = 160. So this is pretty close to the 256 colors of the colormap. Of course you can enhance the resolution via `N=2064`.

Comment: Thank you!
I think ```matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()``` create a colormap using only the four colors I gave. What I need though, is a repeating colormap with only different colors. This is why I wanted to use another cmap to create the new one.

Comment: No, it creates a colormap with 256 colors interpolated between the 160 input colors. There is hence at most one shading level between two colors you provide. As said, you can enhance the resolution via the `N` argument.

Comment: Alright! It's working, thank you.